# Capture STDOUT/STDERR of Windows Applictation

Tags: windows, javascript

I am using an open source application ([conkeror](http://conkeror.org/)) which is configured via a file containing javascript.  Any issues with the javascript is printed to the console.  This is fine under Linux as all the information is shown as long as the it is started from a shell.  However, under Windows none of the information is show even when started from a shell.  Is there a way to make this information displayed in the shell or to capture it in say a file?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when using a command prompt in Windows, one can redirect output to a file by using ">" for example:

```
dir > mylist.txt
```

Would save the output from the dir command to a file named mylist.txt.

So if your executable is named conkeror.exe, try executing it as follows:

```
conkeror.exe > output.txt
```

I did a quick install of Conkeror, but I'm not sure what kind of output you are anticipating, and so I only ended up with a zero-length file.

Comment: Shell redirection doesn't work for "window" applications (Windows makes a distinction between console and window applications).  I'm looking for a work around that will capture the contents of stdout/stderr even though it's a "window" application.

Comment: I think you meant a "GUI application"

Answer (score 0):

[DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) will let you monitor the messages in question, even from a windowed app.

Comment: DebugView does not seem to support capturing stdout or stderr, only specific debug API messages.